# Scala: currying concepts

Tags: function, scala, closures, currying, higher-order-functions

I'm learning Scala by working the exercises from the book "Scala for the Impatient". There're a few questions that test the concept of currying. I've answered them to the best of my understanding but I'd like to run those by the experts here.

> Make a call to `corresponds` that checks whether the elements in an
>   array of strings have the lengths given in an array of integers.

My code:

```
def isCorrespondingLength(arr: Array[String], len: Array[Int]) = {
  arr.corresponds(len)(_.length == _)
}
```

> Implement `corresponds` without currying. Then try the call from the
>   previous exercise. What problem do you encounter?

Ans: The compiler can't derive the type using underscores as in the previous exercise.

```
def myCorresponds(arr: Array[String], that: Seq[Int], f: (String, Int) => Boolean) = {
  arr.zip(that).find(p => f.apply(p._1, p._2)).isDefined
}
```

> Implement an `unless` control abstraction that works just like `if`,
>   but with an inverted condition. Does the first parameter need to be a
>   call-by-name parameter? Do you need currying?

Ans: The first parameter doesn't need to be a call-by-name parameter. Since it's evaluated only once, whether the evaluation happens at call site (as in call-by-value) or inside the function (call-by-name) doesn't affect the outcome. Currying, as in `unless2`, provides a nice control abstraction `unless2(false) { block }` but it's not necessary.

```
 def unless(condition: () => Boolean, block: => Boolean): Boolean = {
   if (!condition()) block else false
 }

 def unless2(condition: => Boolean)(block: => Boolean): Boolean = {
   if (!condition) block else false
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def isCorrespondingLength(arr: Array[String], len: Array[Int]) = {
  myCorresponds(arr, len, _.length == _)
}
```

compiles fine. Now consider what happens if you make `myCorresponds` generic (i.e. work with `A` and `B` rather then `String` and `Int`).

Comment: `isCorrespondingLength` compiles with underscores but `myCorresponds` doesn't. `arr.zip(that).find(f).isDefined` or `arr.zip(that).find(p => f.apply(_ , _)).isDefined` doesn't compile.

Comment: In the first case `f` has to be a function which takes one `(String, Int)` argument for it to compile instead of two arguments; in the second `p => f.apply(_ , _)` is simply not what you want (it's equivalent to `p => { (q, r) => f.apply(q, r) }`. But the difference between them and the working version in your question is not currying.